# Sub Query taking long time due to lakhs of records in table 2

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql-workbench

```
SELECT t1.id,
( SELECT MAX(paid_date) FROM t2 
        where t1.id = t2.due_id  
             t2.deleted_at IS NULL
        ) as lastPaidDate
    WHERE t1.deleted_at IS NULL
```

Here I am trying to get max date from table t2 where table t1.id = t2.due_id  but in table t2 there are many records i.e one to many relationship, I want only max date from t2,It is taking very long time

Comment: Use JOIN instead of correlated subquery. Add suitable indices if they not exists. PS. `FROM t1` was lost somewhere.

Comment: For left join also it is taking long time 
Eg : for 500 rows it is taking 60 seconds
I have 5 lakh rows

Comment: This means that there is no suitable index in `t2`.

Comment: primary id in t1 is mapping to due_id of t2 and there is index for due_id in t2 table

Comment: *there is index for due_id in t2 table* It is not suitable for this query.

Comment: then how it can be done,  please help

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not understood globally, and use words like *million* or *thousand* instead